# jquery how to check an input value previously created with append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bank Iban form created with append() after selection of the country. Each country has is own Iban format, so when the customer choose the country, I proceed to the creation of the form with the right format and It works well.

As I need in a second time to validate the Iban Value, I add in the last append a **onkeyup function()**.

But I don't really like that, cause I need to use a pure javascript function out of the document ready function.

I have been trying to use a **$('#'+lastibancase_id).change function**, but It don't work. I suppose that's because I am trying to operate a check on an html virtual append input...
Do someone face something similar and found a solution to operate a second check on an append form input value ??

Comment: share your code

Comment: Can you provide the minimal code showing the problem you're facing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "on" jQuery function.

like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjoriginal/s6ry7ktb/)

if I have

```
<div id="wrapper">

</div>
<button id='mybutton'>
 ADD thing
</button>
```

Then, the jquery will be

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('button').click(function(){
        $("#wrapper").append("<h1 class='myh1'>Click me</h1><br>")
      })

      //the ON function
      $("#wrapper").on("click", "h1", function(){
        alert("The event works");
      })
    })
```